# Github runner out of disk space after building docker image

Tags: docker, github-actions, diskspace

I have two github repos (call them A and B) that both have a `.github/workflows/build_and_test.yml` file that looks almost identical to this:

```
name: Build and test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build-with-docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      - uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          tags: my_tag:latest
          load: true
          context: .
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max

      - run: docker run my_tag pytest
```

In repo A

- the base image in my `Dockerfile` is `r-base:4.2.1`, which is around 782MB
- the image that I build ends up being around 1.71GB
- the github workflow runs happily from beginning to end (the image builds, the `docker run my_tag pytest` step runs, all is well)

In repo B

- the base image in my `Dockerfile` is `pytorch/pytorch`, which is around 5.82GB
- the image that I build ends up being around 6.4GB
- the github workflow surfaces two problems, one warning and one error, which I'll describe below

The warning is `You are running out of disk space. The runner will stop working when the machine runs out of disk space. Free space left: 0 MB`.

The error happens in the `docker run my_tag pytest` step: I get

```
Unable to find image 'my_tag:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for my_tag, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

which I suspect is a red herring that would go away if I fixed the disk space issue, although I am not certain. (I suspect `Unable to find image` is a red herring because I do not get this error in repo A.)

Is there a way to reduce the disk space used by my `build-push-action` step in repo B without changing its Dockerfile? Should I be using the `no-cache-filters` input described at https://github.com/docker/build-push-action#inputs?

(Possibly related: [How to remove old docker images in continuous integration to save disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984302/how-to-remove-old-docker-images-in-continuous-integration-to-save-disk-space), although I am looking for an answer that better fits my github workflow setup.)

According to https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources github's Linux runners have 14 GB of SSD space.

Update: I tried adding `no-cache: true` to `docker/build-push-action@v3` in repo B, and I see the exact same `running out of disk space` warning and `Unable to find image` error as before.

Confusingly, the github UI has a check mark next to `Run docker/build-push-action@v3`, which indicates that that step ran successfully, so I'm not sure at what exact point in time the runner runs out of disk space:

[image: github workflow screenshot]

Comment: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/2840#issuecomment-1284059930 may have solved the `running out of disk space` issue, I'll post an update after exploring a bit more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this to work thanks to https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/2840#issuecomment-1284059930.

My new github workflow yml file is

```
name: Build Docker image

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build-with-docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Remove unnecessary files
        run: |
          sudo rm -rf /usr/share/dotnet
          sudo rm -rf "$AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY"
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      - uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          tags: my_tag:latest
          load: true
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max

      - name: Run pytest
        run: docker run my_tag pytest
```

The `Remove unnecessary files` step fixed the disk space warning and the `Unable to find image` error went away (so it was indeed a red herring).

Answer (score 7):

The solution provided by the OP is good but it may not suffice. In my case since I had a big docker image (about ~20G), I had to delete many more APT software and further delete the `.git/` directory created after the checkout (normally you don't need the `.git/` into your docker image for production).

I used this and now it works just fine

```yaml
name: Docker build and push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - 
        name: Check disk space
        run: df . -h
      - 
        name: Free disk space
        run: |
          sudo docker rmi $(docker image ls -aq) >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
          sudo rm -rf \
            /usr/share/dotnet /usr/local/lib/android /opt/ghc \
            /usr/local/share/powershell /usr/share/swift /usr/local/.ghcup \
            /usr/lib/jvm || true
          echo "some directories deleted"
          sudo apt install aptitude -y >/dev/null 2>&1
          sudo aptitude purge aria2 ansible azure-cli shellcheck rpm xorriso zsync \
            esl-erlang firefox gfortran-8 gfortran-9 google-chrome-stable \
            google-cloud-sdk imagemagick \
            libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev libmagic-dev ant ant-optional kubectl \
            mercurial apt-transport-https mono-complete libmysqlclient \
            unixodbc-dev yarn chrpath libssl-dev libxft-dev \
            libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev \
            snmp pollinate libpq-dev postgresql-client powershell ruby-full \
            sphinxsearch subversion mongodb-org azure-cli microsoft-edge-stable \
            -y -f >/dev/null 2>&1
          sudo aptitude purge google-cloud-sdk -f -y >/dev/null 2>&1
          sudo aptitude purge microsoft-edge-stable -f -y >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
          sudo apt purge microsoft-edge-stable -f -y >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
          sudo aptitude purge '~n ^mysql' -f -y >/dev/null 2>&1
          sudo aptitude purge '~n ^php' -f -y >/dev/null 2>&1
          sudo aptitude purge '~n ^dotnet' -f -y >/dev/null 2>&1
          sudo apt-get autoremove -y >/dev/null 2>&1
          sudo apt-get autoclean -y >/dev/null 2>&1
          echo "some packages purged"
      - 
        name: Check disk space
        run: |
          sudo dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | sort -nr | head
          df . -h
          sudo du /usr/ -hx -d 4 --threshold=1G | sort -hr | head
      -
        name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - 
        name: Check working space directory
        run: du ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE} -h -d 1
      - 
        name: Get more space
        run: |
          df . -h
          sudo rm -rf ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/.git
          df . -h
      -
        name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/my-app:latest
```

Comment: I had to delete these additional lines once i have used these in the workflow. It worked then